# SetActualResponseType with same method in the same controller with different routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation

**SCENARIO:**

***Web Api 2.2***

I don't know if is the best method, but this is already in production as is and I couldn't change it.

I've a controller with same verbs (several GET) but with different routes.
For example, controller foo:

```
 [Route("foo/{Id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int Id) //Return objectA

[Route("foo/Search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string criteria) //Return objectB

[Route("foo/Anything")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(anything bar) //Return objectC
```

Now I'm creating the Web API Help Documentation and in my `HelpPageConfig.cs`
and I need specify the response type (is different for all methods) with:

```
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(objectA), "foo", "Get");
```

**QUESTION:**

Is possible to make the same with the other methods? When I tried, it says an error: "the definition is already exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use another overload of SetActualResponseType, which accepts parameter names:

```
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(ObjectA), "Home", "Get", "Id");
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(ObjectB), "Home", "Get", "criteria");
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(ObjectC), "Home", "Get", "bar");
```

But, since you are using Web Api 2.2, forget about SetActualResponseType and just do:

```
[Route("foo/{Id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ObjectA))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int Id) //Return objectA

[Route("foo/Search")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ObjectB))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string criteria) //Return objectB

[Route("foo/Anything")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ObjectC))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(anything bar) //Return objectC
```